# Are to many assemblies bad?

Tags: architecture, project, .net-assembly

I've one little question. In many software architectures, for example multi tier or something like the enterprise library, I expand some code in external assemblies. Sometimes my project includes more then 20 assemblies per solution. Now I'm confused... Are 20 assemblies to much? If yes, what I can do in a large project with different "sections" of logic? If i implement the enterprise library, I normaly have 5 assemblies minimally.

Comment: This is probably going to be opinion based, but IMO having 20 assemblies should not be a cause for concern. If you had hundreds of assemblies your start-up time could suffer - otherwise I don't see much down-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twenty assemblies is a long, long way from a problem.  Just for comparison, when I look at Visual Studio right now, I see it having 249 assemblies loaded.  Nothing particularly troublesome about VS on my machine, it does not use a lot of memory (283 MB right now) and starts up in a second or two.

The CLR does not spend heavy resources keeping track of assemblies in general.  The only *possible* disadvantage of having a lot of them is that it can affect the cold-start of your program.  And if your program initialization is not well optimized (VS was *heavily* optimized) and if you need to run from a slow spindle drive then those 20 assemblies can cost you a second worth of foot tapping.  Only matters on interactive programs of course.  ILMerge would be a workaround.

Comment: An alternative to ILMerge is to embed the assembly and use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve` ([blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx)).  Quoting the Mike Barnett, the author of ILMerge, "I think this is fantastic! If I had known about this, I never would have written ILMerge."